# Read File from Google Cloud Storage within Android App

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I want to read  the content of a text-file that's in my Google Cloud Storage. How can I accomplish this within my Android app?

Do I need to publish my app to Google App Engine in order to do so? If not, will it be easier to access my file if I publish it to Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there isn't any official API for Android, but the XML API will work on any platform : https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api-overview

You don't need to create an app on Google App Engine, but it depends on what you want to do, if it's just to get static files it's really not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the xml-Api. I really just want to store my files on the google cloud so that I don't need to publish an app-update whenever I make changes to the content.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement  mobile backend stater to your device .